# ASP.NET MVC automatically change connection string when publishing to server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have and asp.net mvc web app

my issue is I have to change the DB connection string manually in web.config when i try to publish to dev or production server.

```
<!--i comment this when i publish to prod server-->
<add name="HRCornerDbEntities1" connectionString="urlToDevServer" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<!--i comment this when i publish to dev server-->
<add name="HRCornerDbEntities1" connectionString="urlToProdServer" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

is there any approach so the web.config connectionString automatically know when i publish to dev or prod server